# sharing a Google Apps Script to different time zones

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone

I have a Google Sheet with a script attached. I am in EST. I am sharing the sheet with users in different timezones by giving them the link and making them viewers, and they make their own copy of the sheet+script to use. I tried to address the time zone differences as follows:

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("dashboard");
const today = new Date;
const inputColumn = 6; //the column where the input boxes are located
const daysRow = 5;
const subjectRow = 7;
const bodyRow = 9;
const fromRow = 13;
const timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();  //<<<<<<TIME ZONE FIX?


 var daysInAdvance = sheet.getSheetValues(daysRow, inputColumn, 1, 1);
  var dateToCheck = new Date(today.getTime() + (daysInAdvance * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(dateToCheck, timeZone, "MMMM dd, yyyy");
    var time = Utilities.formatDate(dateToCheck, timeZone, "h:mm a");

function sendReminders() {
  var providerEmail = ss.getOwner().getEmail();
  var activeCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(providerEmail);
  var events = activeCal.getEventsForDay(dateToCheck);
  
  for (i=0; i<events.length; i++){
    var emailAddress = "";
    emailBody = sheet.getSheetValues(bodyRow, inputColumn, 1, 1).toString();
    var emailAddress = findEmailAddresses(events[i].getTitle());
  } 

    if (emailAddress == "") {continue}; //skip events with no email address to send to
    
    var timeOfSession = events[i].getStartTime();
          var formattedTime = Utilities.formatDate(timeOfSession, timeZone, "h:mm a");
    emailBody = emailBody.replace(/\<date\>/g, date);
    emailBody = emailBody.replace(/\<time\>/g, formattedTime);
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subjectLine, emailBody, options);
    }
}

function findEmailAddresses(text) {
  var emailRegex = /\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b/g;
  var matches = text.match(emailRegex);
  if (matches) {return matches;} 
}
```

I thought that would set the time zone to wherever the user is but it doesn't seem to work. (I changed it to this from originally having `timeZone = ss.getScriptTimeZone()` which produced the same result.) What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Workaround:

The original timezone of the sheet and its script is retained whenever a user makes a copy of it and wil not automatically change to their timezone. As a workaround, you can have your script get the timezone of the user's primary Google calendar instead. That is, of course, assuming that their primary calendar's timezone is correct or their preferred one.

You can change this part of your script:

```
const timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
```

to:

```
const activeUser = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()
const timeZone = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(activeUser).getTimeZone();
//Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() gets the email address of the user running the script.
//Alternatively, you can also use the email address of the owner of the copy of the sheet.
```

If needed, you can also add the following `if` statement inside the `sendReminders` function to have the script automatically update the sheet's timezone to that of the user running it:

```
if(ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone() != timeZone){
  ss.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(timeZone)
}
```